# IntelliJ IDEA Error Running Application

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created an application (which runs fine in Eclipse), but will not run within IntelliJ IDEA. Every time, it builds and then exits with the error: `Error running Application: 'IntelliJ IDEA IU-163.9166.29' is not a valid JRE home`.

Within IntelliJ I have an SDK set up: 1.8, pointing to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some messing around within the IDE, I have found out that, within the Run/Debug Configurations screen, there was a setting to set the JRE. This wasn't set to the correct value, so the program wasn't running. Upon changing it to the correct value, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that by two steps :

Step One :

`File` -> `Project Structure` -> Make Sure from `project SDK`

[image]

Step Two :

Go to Application name next of run button then click to drop down list and select `Edit Configuration`.

[image]